# Can't access getter in external class

Tags: java, swing, oop, midi

I am trying to access a getter function from another class after creating it in the main method of a program. I have tried accessing the function from other places, but IntelliJ still gives the same error: `cannot resolve method "getCurrentDeviceInfo()"`

The relevant code is as follows:

**Main Method Of Program** (currentMidiDeviceInfo is a public variable)

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    optionsGUI = new optionsGUI();
    currentMidiDeviceInfo = optionsGUI.getCurrentDeviceInfo();
}
```

**OptionsGUI Class**

```
import javax.sound.midi.MidiDevice;
import javax.sound.midi.MidiSystem;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class optionsGUI extends JFrame{

    public MidiDevice.Info currentDeviceInfo;

    public MidiDevice.Info getCurrentDeviceInfo() {
        return currentDeviceInfo;
    }

    public optionsGUI() {

        //Setup JFrame
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setSize(new Dimension(250, 140));

        //Get MIDI Device Info
        MidiDevice.Info[] midiDeviceInfo = MidiSystem.getMidiDeviceInfo();
        currentDeviceInfo = midiDeviceInfo[0];

        //Setup Midi Device Selection Label
        JLabel midiDeviceBoxLabel = new JLabel("Select an MIDI Device");
        add(midiDeviceBoxLabel);

        //Setup Midi Device Selection
        JComboBox midiDeviceBox = new JComboBox(midiDeviceInfo);
        add(midiDeviceBox);

        //Setup OK and Cancel Buttons
        JButton okButton = new JButton("OK");
        okButton.addActionListener(e ->
        {
            currentDeviceInfo = (MidiDevice.Info) midiDeviceBox.getSelectedItem();
            setVisible(false);
        });
        JButton cancelButton = new JButton("Cancel");
        cancelButton.addActionListener(e -> this.setVisible(false));

        //Setup Button Panel
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.add(okButton);
        buttonPanel.add(cancelButton);
        add(buttonPanel);

    }

}
```

Comment: How is the optionsGUI variable defined? Is it just a JFrame?

Comment: use a variable name different from the class name.  e.g. try `opts` instead of `optionsGUI` and see if that resolves the problem.

Comment: I have tried changing the name of the variable, the problem still exists.

Comment: OptionsGUI was declared as a JFrame, I have changed it now, and it works, thanks for the help!

Comment: post the code that tries calling it

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to make the getCurrentDeviceInfo() method static? Or maybe move that code outside of the main method?

Answer (score 0):

optionsGUI was declared as a JFrame, I have changed it now, and it works, thanks for the help!